# ffmpeg changes image aspect when zooming

Tags: ffmpeg

Im trying to zoom on a large image. Image is portrait aspect but when executing command I get video where image is zoomed but squashed to landscape aspect. Im I missing a switch?

```
ffmpeg.exe -i 1.jpg -vf "zoompan=z='min(zoom+0.05,15)'" -t 5 -s "1280x720" out.mp4 -y
```

Answer (score 0):

`-s "1280x720"` option is scaling your output to be "squashed" landscape view. Remove that option and see what it does.

If you wish to fit portrait view to landscape view, use `s` option of `zoompan` filter along with `pad` filter if needs to be widened.

Comment: it only affects output video size not input picture aspect. The issue is that I have huge 12000x18000px picture but want to zoom on  a detail

Comment: it does actually. `-s` injects a `scale` filter to the end(?) of your filterchain. Read up (or experiment) on what it does. Any case, what you need to do then is to specify `s` option of the `zoompan` filter so that the zoomed frame's DAR matches that of the output DAR. (I would also explicitly scale with a followup `setsar` filter as well.

Comment: It just occurred to me that `zoompan` defaults its output size option to be `s=hd720` which is `1280x720`. If you want the zoomed view resolution/aspect to be something else, you do need to specify this option.